# Me da error escáner de puertos mediante un rango de IP

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con mi script en Python. Al hacer un escáner de puertos mediante un rango de IP me hace bien el rango, pero no me hace un escaneo por cada IP y no sé que le pasa. Alguien me puede decir que le pasa. Llevo unos días que lo estoy intentando, pero no lo consigo.

El error que sale es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\josep\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", 
line 11, in result=hola.connect_ex((ip,port)) 
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Aquí está  el código que tengo.

```py
import socket
ip=input("Introduce solo 3 octetos ")
for port in range(80,90):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(f"{ip}.{i}")
    hola=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
    result=hola.connect_ex((ip,port))

    if result == 0:
        print(f"Disponible -> %s:%s" % (ip, port) + "\n")
    else:
        print(f"Puerto {port} no abierto \n")
        hola.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes especificar la dirección completa, 4 octetos, en

```
result=hola.connect_ex((ip,port))
```

Ahí le estas pasando sólo los tres octetos que ingresó el usuario.

Además está mal indentado; la conexión la haces una vez por puerto, no por (direccion, puerto).

El código correcto es:

```
import socket

ip=input("Introduce solo 3 octetos ")

for port in range(80,90):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        direccion = f"{ip}.{i}"
        print(direccion)
        hola=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result=hola.connect_ex((direccion,port))

        if result == 0:
            print(f"Disponible -> %s:%s" % (direccion, port) + "\n")
        else:
            print(f"Puerto {port} no abierto \n")
        hola.close()
```

produce:

```
Introduce solo 3 octetos 172.16.0
172.16.0.1
Disponible -> 172.16.0.1:80

172.16.0.2
Disponible -> 172.16.0.2:80

172.16.0.3
Puerto 80 no abierto 


... etc, etc, etc
```